# Regex match and replace with pattern

Tags: c#, regex

My string can be **"Wings U15 W"** or **"Wings U15W"** or **"Wings U15M"** or **"Wings U15 M"** I would like to get output as **"Wings U15"** my code as below.

```
string _Input = "Wings U15 W";

if (Regex.Match(_Input, " U[0-9]{2} (W|M)").Success)
{
    string pattern = "U[0-9]{2} (W|M)";
    string replacement = "";
    _Input = Regex.Replace(_Input, pattern, replacement);

}

MessageBox.Show(_Input);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to match any chars up to `U`, 2 digits, an optional space and `W` or `M` at the end of the string, use

```
var m = Regex.Match(_Input, @"^(.* U[0-9]{2}) ?[WM]$");
var result = "";
if (m.Success) 
{
    result = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FhM4BZ/1)

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(.* U[0-9]{2})` - Group 1:

  - `.*` - any 0+ chars other than LF symbol, as many as possible (replace with `\w+` if you plan to match any 1+ word chars (letters, digits or `_`))
  - - a space (replace with `\s` to match any whitespace)
  - `U` - an `U`
  - `[0-9]{2}` - 2 digits
- `?` - an optional space (replace with `\s?` to match any 1 or 0 whitespace chars)
- `[WM]` - `W` or `M`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Thank you very much. And how can I add more options to [WM] for Wings U15 MU or Wings U15 WU?

Comment: @Kerberos To match `MU` or `WU` use `[MW]U`. If `U` is optional, add `?` after it.

Comment: Thank you again. This is very useful. I arranged as @"^(.* U[0-9]{2}) ?[WM]?U$